# Compare two tables. Show values only in one table

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

I have two tables. Each table has a column with a reference number. Most of the records in these tables are the same but there are some which are in one table but not in the other.

How can I compare these columns and pick out the records which are only in one table?

I could write a MapBasic program that loops through each record and looks it up in the other table but I'm wondering if there is a simpler SQL-like way of doing this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's say we have two tables: **Tab1** with field **Field1**, **Tab2** with field **Field2**.

We want to select records from **Tab1** which **Field1** values is not present in **Field2** of **Tab2**.

In MapInfo: menu `Query->SQL Select...`

- Columns: `*`
- from Tables: `Tab1`
- where Condition: `not Field1 in (select Field2 from Tab2)`

In MapBasic window it will be: `Select * from Tab1 where not Field1 in (select Field2 from Tab2) into Selection`